# Is there a website / api where I can access historic coinbase data?

Tags: api, coinbase.com

Is there a website / api where I can access historic coinbase data for Bitcoin?

I know about blockchair.com but they charge for the coinbase data.

Anywhere that supplies this for free?

Comment: For what purposes you need such data? Education or what?

Answer (score 1):

You can request this data via the API.

A request could look like that 
https://api.pro.coinbase.com/products/BTC-EUR/candles?granularity=60&start=2018-11-09T17:11:08Z&end=2018-11-09T18:11:08Z